# change event triggering continuously in vue-multi-select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-multiselect

I have a multiselect dropdown in vuejs below:

```
        <h4>Symptoms</h4>
        <div class="select">
          <multi-select
            search
            v-model="selected_symptoms_list"
            :options="multiDropDownOptions"
            :selectOptions="receivedData.symptoms_list"
            :btnLabel="multiselectBtnLabel"
            @selectionChanged="FilterBySelectedItem"
          />
          <span class="select-highlight"></span>
          <span class="select-bar"></span>
        </div>
```

`receivedData` variable receives values through api call when page is loaded.

`FilterBySelectedItem` method calls api when some item is selected from the dropdown and it also receives the data in `receivedData` variable so the dropdown could be populated again with new values.

But using `receivedData` variable in two different api calls causing the event to trigger continuously and making api calls written inside`FilterBySelectedItem`.

Here is the [doc](https://github.com/IneoO/vue-multi-select) for vue-multi-select

How can I tackle this problem.